# Missing argument for parameter #1 in call

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, swift3

Не могу разобраться почему ошибка...

```
//Значения в массивы добавляются по таймеру    
var counter = [Int]()
var counterForInterval = [Int]()

    func arrayRange() {

        var minuteInterval = [Int]()

        if counter.count == 4 {
            minuteInterval = counterForInterval.dropFirst()
        }
        if counter.count == 8 {
            minuteInterval = counterForInterval.dropFirst()
        }

        // Далее используется minuteInterval
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что у них разные типы. Используйте:

```
[Int](counterForInterval.dropFirst())
```

или

```
counterForInterval.dropFirst().sorted()
```